# Anything after DOS FOR /F loop not executing

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

I've had a jolly good search through the world of google to find a similar problem to mine,  but I can't find any examples of people doing things outside of their FOR /F loops and so I am resigned to creating a new thread.

I am using a FOR /F loop to execute a Ruby Gem once per line it finds in a reference file, which it does perfectly.  The problem is, when it has finished scrolling through its reference file and executed the Ruby Gem the correct amount of times, it will not complete anything else in the .CMD file outside of the FOR /F loop.

Here is my .CMD code:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%a in (c:\cygwin\usr\work\easy.lst) do (
c:\ruby191\bin\scrapitalist website -u http://www.website.com/%%a/%%c/%%b.html -o     C:\cygwin\usr\autobets\work\%%b_%%c.easy
)
copy c:\cygwin\usr\work\*.easy c:\cygwin\usr\autobets\work\easy.imp
```

The easy.lst file has two lines of data in it.

The loop works fine, executing the Ruby Gem and creating *.easy files as output, however, the COPY command never executes.  I can replace the copy with an ECHO, or in fact anything, but it will not execute.

I cannot see what I am missing from my FOR /F syntax - any ideas peeps?

Thanks

Comment: May I suggest a UNIX-style shell? The syntax is much more powerful, and a lot saner. It looks like you have cygwin installed already, so why not just use the bash shell that comes with it?

Comment: @tdammers that's a fair suggestion, but that's also like suggesting coding in C# when the OP wants assembly, whatever the reason might be.

Answer (score 10):

I suppose that `scrapitalist` is a batch file itself, therefore it stops the batch file, but as the FOR-loop is cached, it work to the end.

To solve this you only need a single `call` as prefix.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%a in (c:\cygwin\usr\work\easy.lst) do (
  call c:\ruby191\bin\scrapitalist website -u http://www.website.com/%%a/%%c/%%b.html -o     C:\cygwin\usr\autobets\work\%%b_%%c.easy
)
copy c:\cygwin\usr\work\*.easy c:\cygwin\usr\autobets\work\easy.imp
```

Comment: jeb - You are absolutely right, this resolved the issue.  Annoying thing, I had tried it with the 'Call' command, so I must have made a syntax error at that time. Grrrr!  Many thanks!